# New-Cluster Installing windows failover cluster remotely

Tags: windows, powershell, failovercluster

I'm working on a script which will install the windows failover cluster from a remote server
Remote server is hosting windows server 2016.
Cluster contains 2 Nodes Node1 and Node 2 of Windows server 2019

I ran below cmdlet from the remote server and when the node OS was Win 2016 then it created the failover cluster fine without any error, but when the node OS was Windows Server 2019 and the remote server from where I'm running the cmdlet OS is 2016 then I get below error

```
New-Cluster -Name "newcluster" -Node "win201906","win201905" -StaticAddress "10.0.3.22"

The clustered role was not successfully created. For more information view the report file below.
Report file location: C:\windows\cluster\Reports\Create Cluster Wizard winclus2021 on 2020.08.06 At 19.32.37.htm
New-Cluster : An error occurred while performing the operation.
    An error occurred while creating the cluster 'winclus2021'.
    An error occurred creating cluster 'winclus2021'.
    The parameter is incorrect
```

file containing the error is generic

[image]

As an alternative I thought of running the new-cluster command on the node itself using invoke-command but it gives the error message

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Servername {
        New-Cluster -Name $using:Clustername -Node $using:Clusternodes -StaticAddress $using:Clusip
}

There was an error adding node 'win201906' to the cluster
    You do not have administrative privileges on the server 'win201906.constosonet.com'.
    Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
At line:2 char:9
+         Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Reports[0].Servername {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [New-Cluster], ClusterCmdletException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.NewClusterCommand
    + PSComputerName        : win201905
```

Above permission error incorrect as I'm running the cmdlet using domain joined account which is local admin on both the nodes. And I've logged in with that same account on that remote server.

Can you please suggest a better way of creating cluster from a remote server? as both of the above method seems to be difficult to achieve